# Authorization header doesn't confirm to the required format - Python Cosmos-db api

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am using the python cosmos-db library to: create a database, container and user.

The azure cosmos instance is running locally.

Using the master key, I can successfully create a database, container and user.

However, once I have a user and generate the token, I receive the following error when I try to query the db:

***Authorization header doesn't confirm to the required format. Please verify and try again.***

I have tried executing the entire sample code from Microsoft but it throws the same error. The sample code can be found here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/4f96d8a8dfde9b4cac9d2103b5f58d5705b26ded/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos/samples/access_cosmos_with_resource_token.py

This is the snippet of code used to open the token client and query the collection.

```
def run_sample():
    client = cosmos_client.CosmosClient(HOST, {"masterKey": MASTER_KEY})
#</configureConnectivity>


    try:
        try:
            db = client.create_database(DATABASE_ID)
        except exceptions.CosmosResourceExistsError:
            db = client.get_database_client(DATABASE_ID)

        try:
            container = db.create_container(
                id=CONTAINER_ID, partition_key=PARTITION_KEY
            )
        except exceptions.CosmosResourceExistsError:
            container = db.get_container_client(CONTAINER_ID)

        user = create_user_if_not_exists(db, USERNAME)

        # Permission to perform operations on all items inside a container
        permission_definition = {
            "id": CONTAINER_ALL_PERMISSION,
            "permissionMode": documents.PermissionMode.All,
            "resource": container.container_link,
        }

        permission = create_permission_if_not_exists(user, permission_definition)
        token = {}
        token[container.id] = permission.properties["_token"]

        # Use token to connect to database
        token_client = cosmos_client.CosmosClient(HOST, token)
        token_db = token_client.get_database_client(DATABASE_ID)
        token_container = token_db.get_container_client(CONTAINER_ID)

       # Query for items in a certain partition
        token_client_query(token_container, USERNAME_2)


def token_client_query(container, username):
    try:
        for item in container.query_items(
            query="SELECT * FROM my_container c WHERE c.username=@username",
            parameters=[{"name": "@username", "value": username}],
            partition_key=username,
        ):
            print(json.dumps(item, indent=True))
    except exceptions.CosmosHttpResponseError:
        print("Error in querying item(s)")
```

From this, I receive a 401 response. any ideas as to how I can solve this?

Comment: We usually see this error when the SDK and Cosmos account type don't match. For instance, when using the SQL API SDK to talk to Cosmos account provisioned as a Table API. Please check if this is the case with you.

Comment: @KalyanChanumolu-MSFT This was not the case. It turns out the code sample provided did not encode the token before using it. I used the urllib library and the following function urllib.parse.quote_plus(token) to encode before passing it to the http request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the above comment, the issue was the format of the token.

> The authorization string should be encoded before adding it to the REST request to ensure that it contains no invalid characters. Ensure that it's Base64 encoded using MIME RFC2045.

[Access control in the Azure Cosmos DB SQL API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/access-control-on-cosmosdb-resources)

From this, I used the urllib library to encode the token and pass it to the http request which solved the issue as the response was the required document.

```
import urllib.parse   
urllib.parse.quote_plus(token[container.id])
```