# Azure Cosmos Table DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-tables

I'm trying to query an Azure Cosmos Table DB via Postman but am unable to get past authentication with the error: "Authorization header doesn't confirm to the required format. Please verify and try again"

I can successfully query a Cosmos NOSQL DB so there must be some difference in the request, but I cannot find it documented anywhere.

The format of the Authorization header currently is

```
type={typeoftoken}&ver={tokenversion}&sig={hashsignature}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authorization header doesn't confirm to the required format - Python Cosmos-db api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64566024/authorization-header-doesnt-confirm-to-the-required-format-python-cosmos-db-a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the REST API, it works only with NOSQL API. To query Table API you should use the SDK

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/

Comment: fyi this should be a comment, not an answer.